# Limit distribution of the joint distribution of maximum and minimum of a sequence of random variables

Tags: distributions, references, convergence, extreme-value

Assume we have a sequence $\mathsf{X}_1,\mathsf{X}_2,\mathsf{X}_3,...$ of iid random variables. Then the [Fisher-Tippet-Gnedenko theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem) shows that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\max\{\mathsf{X}_1,\mathsf{X}_2,\dotsc,\mathsf{X}_n \}-b_n}{a_n}\leq x\right) \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{d}G(x),  $$
at least if $\mathsf{X}$ is in the domain of attraction. In chapter 2 in *Extreme value theory - An introduction* by de Haan and Ferreira (2006) they find the joint limit distribution of the $k$ largest order statstics of this kind of sequence. Having found such order statistics (and especially the maximum) they also derive the joint limit distribution for the $k$ lowest order statistics included the minimum. What I am now wondering is if there is a result that in a sense combine these, i.e. do we now anything about the possible non-degenerate limit distribution of
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\max\{\mathsf{X}_1,\mathsf{X}_2,\dotsc,\mathsf{X}_n \}-b_n}{a_n}\leq x,\frac{\min\{\mathsf{X}_1,\mathsf{X}_2,\dotsc,\mathsf{X}_n \}-c_n}{d_n}\leq y\right),$$

or something related. I have added some normalising constants since the sequence maximum and minimum must be normalised or else they will converge to the maximum and the minimum of the support respectively, but of course, they need not be normalised in this fashion.

Comment: Asymptotically, the min and max become independent.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have a reference or a proof of that?

Comment: In this setting you implicitly assume the underlying distribution $F$ is continuous with density function $f,$ in which case the joint distribution of $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ has a density proportional to $f(x_1)(F(x_n)-F(x_1))^{n-2}f(x_n).$  As $n$ grows large, that middle term approaches a constant $(1-2/n)^n\approx \exp(-2),$ implying this joint density is closely approximated by a multiple of $f(x_1)f(x_n):$ that's asymptotic independence in a sufficiently strong form to conclude you can apply the limiting theorems separately to the minimum and maximum.